# ungzip the gizpped war

Tags: gzip

I have gzipped a war file like this `gzip mytest.war`. I try to ungzip it like it `--ungzip mytest.war.gz`, it said command can't be found. How can I ungzip it?

Moreover, how can gzip and ungzip a particular folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat covered the answer in its entirety, but here are some more verbose self-help explanations.

Generally speaking, the way to get help on Unix (and, of course, Linux) is the `man` (manual) command. `man gzip` would have answered your question. The answer's already there in the ‘Synopsis’ section (this may be the reason for the negative vote your question got). You can even say `man man` to learn how the Unix online manual is organised.

In terms of compression tools, Unix separates the notion of an archiver and a compressor. Tools like ZIP came from the MS-DOS ecosystem where applications had to be all-inclusive (do everything, do it as well as you can) because it was difficult to combine the results of programs. On Unix, where it's very easy (nay, *required*) to pipe data from one command to another, the mentality is ‘do one thing, do it well’. You archive files together in an archive file using tools like `tar`, then `gzip` the result to compress it. Modern versions of the standard archivers can do this for you (`tar` can automatically `gzip` or `bzip2` its resulting files, and it can uncompress automatically too).

To archive and compress a folder all at once, this is standard practice:

```
tar czvf file.tar.gz some-folder
```

The man page for `tar` explains the arguments bunched up in the second ‘word’. Briefly, `c`=create, `z`=gzip, `v`=verbose, `f`=the resultant filename follows. This is equivalent to this:

```
tar cvf file.tar some-folder
gzip file.tar
```

Or

```
tar cv some-folder | gzip file.tar
```

The last two forms give you more flexibility in case you want to use something else to compress. (or to adjust the compression level of `gzip`, for instance)

Comment: Stdout is the default, so `-f -` is redundant. `tar c folder` (or `cv` if you prefer) is quite enough.

Comment: Thanks! (you learn something new every day) Answer updated.

Answer (score 12):

There is no `ungzip`. You might have a `gunzip`, and if you don't you should be able to `gzip -d`. Read `man gzip` for details.

`gzip` handles single files only. If you want to archive whole directories, use `zip`, or `tar`, or `cpio` (or ...); or `jar` since you seem to be handling Java archives.